# When a fragment is added to the project android application crashes

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments

I have included a new fragment to  project. After adding the fragment, app crashed. And I want to add three fragments to my project. I have gone through answers provided for similar kind of issues but unfortunately they are not providing the expected solution.[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: post your error logcat .

Comment: @BhavyaGandhi I have edited the post with logcat.

Comment: error is showing on mainactivity... include that screenshot too

Comment: @Rashiq edited the question with the screenshots of the main activity. Thank you for the interest

Comment: Just comment your 38th line in mainactivity and try rebuiling it.

Comment: @Rashiq when I add that comment again the app get crashed

Comment: There is something yu are doing wrong here. Its jus a simple error i guess

Comment: @Rashiq maybe, but how to find it?

Comment: As of i know, the issue is in the 38th line... or jus tell me where is the redirecting to when u click the blued error line in logcat

Comment: @Rashiq I still can’t find a solution

Comment: Did yu check to which line the error is redirecting??

Comment: @Rashiq now the line you mentioned is not displaying..

Comment: Means?? So wats the error now?

Comment: @Rashiq I again created the fragments for the project using another method. It was successful. Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please be sure that the `compileSdkVersion` is the same as support versions. Do not forget to clean and build.

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:27.0.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.0'
}
```